# Unable to obtain accuracy score for my linear

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on my regression model based on the IMDB data, to predict IMDB value. On my linear-regression, i was unable to obtain the accuracy score.

my line of code:

```
metrics.accuracy_score(test_y, linear_predicted_rating)
```

Error :

```
ValueError: continuous is not supported
```

if i were to change that line to obtain the r2 score,

```
metrics.r2_score(test_y,linear_predicted_rating)
```

i was able to obtain r2 without any error. 
Any clue why i am seeing this?

Thanks.

Edit:
One thing i found out is `test_y` is panda data frame whereas the `linear_predicted_rating` is in numpy array format.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

metrics.accuracy_score is used to measure classification accuracy, it can't be used to measure accuracy of regression model because it doesn't make sense to see accuracy for regression - predictions rarely can equal the expected values. And if predictions differ from expected values by 1%, the accuracy will be zero, though these predictions are great

Here are some metrics for regression: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#regression-metrics

Comment: Great!thanks for the link, looks like there is no accuracy metrics for regression.

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense to see accuracy for regression - predictions rarely can equal the expected values. And if predictions differ from expected values by 1%, the accuracy will be zero, though these predictions are great.

Answer (score 14):

**NOTE:** Accuracy (e.g. classification accuracy) is a measure for classification, not regression so we can't calculate accuracy for a regression model. For regression, one of the matrices we've to get the score (ambiguously termed as accuracy) is ***R-squared*** (**R<sup>2</sup>**).

You can get the R<sup>2</sup> score (i.e accuracy) of your prediction using the `score(X, y, sample_weight=None)` function from `LinearRegression` as follows by changing the logic accordingly.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train,y_train)
r2_score = regressor.score(x_test,y_test)
print(r2_score*100,'%')
```

output (a/c to my model)

```
86.23%
```

Answer (score 2):

The above is R squared value and not the accuracy :

```
# R squared value
metrics.explained_variance_score(y_test, predictions)
```

Comment: I thought the r^2 - explained variance was the accuracy

Answer (score 0):

What does your variables look like. Code below works well.

```
from sklearn import metrics
test_y, linear_predicted_rating = [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,5]
metrics.accuracy_score(test_y, linear_predicted_rating)
```

Comment: the linear_predicted_rating seems to be in np array whereas the test_y is panda data frame.;  https://pastebin.com/yuh0p703

Comment: it works fine when i used metrics.r2_score(test_y, linear_predicted_rating) though.

Answer (score 0):

You can not predict the accuracy of regression model,however you can analyze your model using Mean absolute error ,Mean squared error ,Root mean squared error,Max error,median error R-square etc.
for reference 
you can go [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#explained-variance-score) to gain more knowledge